# How do I get Sublime Text's open directory to show files in GUI?

Tags: shortcut-keys, sublime-text, autohide

I have opened sublime editor to edit some files in directory.
It was shown correctly. Than I have pressed something + 'arrow button' and sublime became for half of display. I have tried to fix it, with different hotkeys and I can see nothing now except Ubuntu panel where I can see sublime menu (I tried reload editor and reopen another directory - nothing helped).

How do I get Sublime Text's open directory to show files in GUI editor?

Comment: **F11** helps me to get full screen mode, but I can not switch to usual mode view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the side panel, right? Follow this sequence of menus: `View -> Side Bar -> Show Side Bar`.

Comment: I have only `View -> Side Bar -> Show Side Bar` and checked it in two directions - issue is not fixed.